# jQuery plugin, get .data() for original element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've created a dropdown jquery plugin. That hides a regular html select and adds a div and a number of child divs as options to show instead.

Following the general rule of thumb I am initializing the plugin like so:

```
$.fn.dropdown = function (options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (undefined === $(this).data('dropdown')) {
            var dropdown = new $.dropdown(this, options);
            $(this).data('dropdown', dropdown);
        }
    });
};
```

I am also copying any class given to the select element to the replacement div

When trying to get the data for the element by using a class as a selector, the selector is obviously returning the generated div in the element array.

This results in a 'data is not defined' error for the div.

Should I change something from the plugin or expect whoever uses the plugin to get the data by using an id instead of a class to select the element after initialization?

Comment: how do you use this function? `$('select').dropdown()` ?

Comment: I'm using it with a class  selector "$('.select').dropdown();

that's my issue, if i'm finding dropdowns by class

Comment: please give some more code. I execute your code and face with this error: `$.dropdown is not a constructor`

Comment: I'd have to post the whole plugin though

Answer (score 0):

Well you really don't have many options here. Inside of you `$.dropdown` constructor just create one more data reference to `this` instance. It's quite cheap anyway since it's going to be just a object reference:

```
$.dropdown = function(element, options) {
    // ... newElement is what replaces original select
    newElement.data('dropdown', this);
};
```